# Define global constants in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to define global constant variable for my API url, which I want to access at many places.

In what type of file it will defined, and how to access them.

Comment: old post but relevant answers are there with respect to using `environment.ts`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the files `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` (for production) to define all your global const and call them like this :

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  apiVersion: '1',
}
```

in other component or service

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

environment.apiVersion
```